# Express JS redirect with headers

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

Using express JS I'm trying to add some headers to the redirection I'm returning 
However, everything I tried just work for the response headers and not for the request headers of the redirection. I.E., when inspecting it with the developer tools I can see the response headers but when the next call is made, I can not see the request headers

```
req.headers['x-custom-header'] = 'value'
res.setHeader('x-custom-header', 'value')    
res.redirect('example.com')
```

Does anybody could explain how the response and request headers work on ExpressJS?

Answer (score 2):

A redirect just does a redirect.  It tells the browser to go to that new location with standard, non-custom headers.  You cannot set custom headers on the next request after the redirect.  The browser simply doesn't do that.

The usual way to pass some type of parameters in a redirect is to put them in a query string for the redirect URL or, in some cases, to put them in a cookie.  In both cases of query string parameters and data in a cookie, those will be available to your server when the browser sends you the request for the redirected URL.

It also may be worth revisiting why you're redirecting in the first place and perhaps there's a different flow of data/urls that doesn't need to redirect in the first place.  We'd have to know a lot more about what this actual operation is trying to accomplish to make suggestions there.

If your request is being processed by an Ajax call, then you can program the code receiving the results of the Ajax call to do anything you want it to do (including add custom headers), but if it's the browser processing the redirect and changing the page URL to load a new page, it won't pay any attention to custom headers on the redirect response.

> Can anybody explain how the response and request headers work on ExpressJS?

Express is doing exactly what you told it to do.  It's attaching the custom headers to the response that goes back to the browser.  It's the browser that does not attach those same headers to the next request to the redirected URL.  So, this isn't an Express thing, it's a browser thing.

Comment: I totally explain myself wrongly.
I'm implementing a middleware (using express js) to handle authentication between a 3rd party app and an AD server 
The user requests the app, this uses proxied authentication and calls the middleware. The middleware creates a SAML request and sends it to the AD. The AD replies granting/denying access. The middleware should attach a header in order for the application to recognise the user in case the authentication has been successful. 
There is where I was trying to add a header to the response.  
Do you think is there a better way to do so?

Comment: @Lt. - If you want the auth to "stick" for future requests from that user, then you would typically use an encyrpted cookie.  Then, your middleware can also look first for the presence of the cookie to indicate prior authentication.  If you want others to help, please edit your question to add this further explanation about the AD, SAML, etc...

Comment: thanks for the responses. I've posted a (hopefully better explained) post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197971/rstudio-proxied-authetication

Comment: @Lt. - We shouldn't just leave this question/answer hanging here.  If you think I answered your original question about headers and a redirect as your question was written, then we can finish it off if you accept this answer.  Otherwise, let me know what else is needed here to finish it.  I've commented on your other question as best I can.