# RStudio proxied authetication

Tags: express, authentication, rstudio, rstudio-server

I've setup proxied authentication for RStudio Server.

RStudio Server is redirecting to a middleware implemented using Express JS
The middleware creates a request to the authentication server and then parses the response from it.

Then the middleware adds the `X-RStudio-Username` header to the response, which is a re-direction to the RStudio. However, the header is added to the response from the middleware, and then the browser doesn't keep it when it redirects to RStudio Server

Since the browser request doesn't have the required header, RStudio requests the authentication again creating an infinite loop

How should I approach this case?

What would be the best way to add the required header for RStudio Server?

Comment: You can't use a browser redirect if you need custom headers on the redirected URL because the browser does not put custom headers on a redirect it is following just like you never get custom headers on a URL you type in the browser URL bar.  You could use Ajax for the initial request, see the redirect response come back,  get the custom headers off it and then create a new request with Ajax that has the custom headers on it.

Comment: There's something wrong with the general design because if you're trying to get the browser itself (not Ajax calls) to process these URLs, the browser doesn't ever put these type of custom headers on a URL that it fetches.  It never adds custom headers when you type a URL in the URL bar, when you click in a link in a web page or when it gets a redirect URL.  It's just not something the browser does.  So, any architecture that expects custom headers after a redirect will have to be used via Ajax, not via plain browser processing of the URL.

Comment: Now I realise that there is a design problem. 
The steps would be: 1. RStudio redirects to a lambda 2. Lambda uses express to create a SAML requests and parses the response. 3. Then, somehow I have to send that data back to RStudio but also adding a header. In this scenario, would it make sense to add a web server proxy (such as NGinx) as a new layer? In order to add those headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser won't add this header for you. You need to add it in the layer that proxies traffic through to RStudio Server. If you don't have such a layer already, you will need to add it using e.g. Nginx. This layer could authenticate the request using whatever mechanism your auth provider supports and add the `X-RStudio-Username` header (which we recommend renaming for security reasons).

Since you're using RStudio Server Pro, our support team would be happy to help you with this:

support@rstudio.com

You'll also be glad to know that we're working on SAML support for an upcoming release of RStudio Server Pro!